# How to taylor expand a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, tensors

### Question

Is there some nice way to Taylor expand a tensor in a coordinate invariant way? (I expect some christoffel symbols would be involved)

After searching on the internet I found [this](https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s2-32/1/87/1438010?redirectedFrom=PDF) however, it is behind a pay wall.

Comment: Not behind a pay wall, I just clicked on "pdf" on the right side of the page and [got the paper](https://bit.ly/2zQm641) (I had to shorten the url to make it fit in the comment, the original was some garbage that completely passed the character limit allowed in comments). The paper is 6 pages long.

Comment: @IvoTerek I clicked on the pdf I can't seem to access it without it saying: "Get access to the full version of this article. View access options below."